# Mysql - Is there a better way to retrieve data from two tables with the same id?

Tags: mysql, select, join

Hi I have the following Mysql code that works but I was wondering if there was a better, shorter, more efficient way of doing it?

```
select
images.*,
posts.*
from
mjbox_images AS images,
mjbox_posts AS posts
where
images.post_id = 3 AND posts.post_id = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = 3
```